# React Native Redux store dispatches reducers correctly, but doesn't update UI component

Tags: react-native, redux

Working on a cancer treatment app in react native:

Current functionality: when I move the sliders and change the date on my app, it dispatches changes to the redux store successfully. Unfortunately, my UI doesn't update, even though I am calling the same `store` from the presentational components that I called for dispatch.

That results in this:
[GIF of redux store changing while UI is static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoDlp.gif)

Printing via

```
store.getState();
store.subscribe(() =>
  console.log(store.getState())
);
```

I tried using subscription, but it seems like this isn't the right way to go about this. Thoughts?

snippets from my code (all in one small file, linked below)

Action

```
//action
function set_num_treatments(num) {
  return {
    type: SET_NUM_TREATMENTS,
    num: num
  }
}
```

setting the title

```
SET_NUM_TREATMENTS = "SET_NUM_TREATMENTS"
```

main reducer

```
function main_reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_PAGE_VIEW:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        current_page: action.page_of_interest
      })
    case SET_NUM_TREATMENTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        num_treatments: action.num
      })
    case SET_INTER_TREATMENT_INTERVAL:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        inter_treatment_interval: action.weeks_between_treatments
      })
    case SET_TREATMENT_START_DATE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        treatment_start_date: action.date
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
  return state
}
```

Here's where I start the store & produce the printing functionality

```
let store = createStore(main_reducer);
store.getState();
store.subscribe(() =>
console.log(store.getState())
);
```

here's the presentational components

```
class TreatmentSettings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    const props = this.props
    const {store} = props
    const state = store.getState()
    return(
      <View style={styles.treatment_option_slider_card}>
      <Text style={styles.my_font, styles.tx_settings_header}>{state.num_treatments} Treatments</Text>
      <Slider step={1} minimumValue={1} maximumValue={20} value={12}
              onValueChange={(num_treatments) => {store.dispatch(set_num_treatments(num_treatments))}}  />
      <Text style={styles.my_font, styles.tx_settings_header}>X Weeks Between Treatments</Text>
      <Slider step={1} minimumValue={1} maximumValue={4} value={2} style={{marginBottom:60}}
                    onValueChange={(value) => {store.dispatch(set_inter_treatment_interval(value))}}
                    />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

These final two components hold the main containers for the app

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={createStore(main_reducer)}>
        <AppContainer />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render(){
    return(

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TreatmentSettings store={store} />
            <Text>footertext</Text>
          </View>
    )
  }
}
```

the one gist file is here if you want to see it all: https://github.com/briancohn/learning-redux/blob/navigation_addn/App.js
I really appreciate the help—
Thanks in advance!
-Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way you are updating the store is fine but there’s something wrong with how your components are listening to the changes.
It seems you meant to use `connect` from `react-redux` for the containers to connect to the store. Then you can use `mapStateToProps` to get the data from the store to pass into the components as props. Check https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options for example.